# Ctrl-D signal confirmation to avoid exiting terminal

Tags: terminal

I sometimes accidentally press Ctrl-D while using a terminal, exiting the terminal or closing screen/tmux.

Can I avoid this by having a confirmation before exit like this?

```
Are you sure you want to quit? [Y/n]
```

or

```
Press Ctrl-D again to quit
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer in general is "no", you are providing an end of file (EOF) indication to the program running in the terminal/screen/tmux, but bash for example allows you to say

```
IGNOREEOF=4
```

and then it takes 4 control-D characters in a row to exit the shell.